# How to update "downloadable cartridge" in OpenShift online

Tags: openshift

I've read that when a downloadable cartridge is installed, OpenShift will fetch the cartridge contents from the specified repository address. However, when I push subsequent changes to the git repository, OpenShift does not seem to detect the change. How do I update the contents in OpenShift gears correspondingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to uninstall the downloadable cartridge, and then reinstall it.  Hopefully the cartridge author did not make the cleanup script delete any data that you want to persist.

Comment: How to uninstall the downloadable cartridge without deleting the application? (I am using OpenShift online, not Origin) Actually I am the cartridge author but totally cannot find any relevant information in OpenShift docs. Many cartridge files are chowned as root, making it hard to do a manual update.

Comment: If this is the main web cartridge, you can not uninstall it, but if it's an add on cartridge you can use the rhc cartridge remove command to remove it.

Comment: So there is no other way but to remove the app in the case where I need to update the main cartridge?

Comment: The best way would probably be to use the rhc snapshot command to backup the application, delete it, then re-create it with the new cartridge.